# Skew symmetric subtracted from Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

How can I prove that for any skew-symmetric matrix $S$ with $S^T = -S$, $I - S$ is non-singular and $(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)$ is an orthogonal Matrix (cayley transform of S).

Comment: Are you asking if $(I-S)^{-1}(I-S)=I$ is orthogonal?

Comment: Yeah, how can I prove it's orthogonality?

Comment: It is identity matrix ...

Comment: Thanks. So, just like $A^{-1}A$

Comment: What can I say about the singularity of $I-S$?

Answer (score 0):

Let  $Sx=x $,then $S^TSx=S^Tx=-Sx=-x $. Since  $S^TS $ is positive semidefinite,  $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of  $S^TS $, hence $x=0$.

Comment: Can you explain how you equated $-S^Tx$ to -x?

Comment: $Sx=x$, hence $S^Tx=-Sx=-x$.

Comment: Can you also say why can you assume that Sx = x in the first place?
Also, how x = 0 should that I-S is non-singular?

Comment: $I-S$ is non-singular $ \iff ker(I-S)=\{0\}$. Now let $x \in ker(I-S)$, then $Sx=x$. Above I have shown that this implies $x=0$. Hence $  ker(I-S)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense! Thanks. Can you say, how can I prove orthogonality for (I-S)^-1 * (I+S). I just added this in the question.